# Failed to connect to MySQL at localhost

Tags: mysql, connection, localhost

I recently installed MySQL on my machine using MySQL installer. I am using it as part of an Apache Tomcat server I'm running on localhost.

I linked the database to Netbeans and everything was working fine. A couple of weeks ago I accidentally shut off my machine - the battery became disconnected - and when I turned it back on I could not connect to the database.

Whether I tried to connect via the command line, MySQL workbench or Netbeans I got an error telling me I could not connect to the database.

I've tried the following to fix the problem
-Reinstalled MySQL server, workbench, etc
-Reinstalled MySQL in different location
-Stopped MySQL via the services window and started it again
-Reconnected to Netbeans

Here's an example of the errors.

I get this when testing the connection while creating a new connection in Workbench:

[image]

After I make a connection (ignoring the fact the connection test fails) and trying to connect (still in Workbench)

[image]

Can someone please please help me? This is for my final year college project and I haven't been able to do anything for the past couple of weeks because of this. It's really annoying and I've tried everything I can think of.

Comment: You didn't say if MySQL is actually running while you run these tests. Please note that "actually running" != "I started the service". You also didn't say what you found in the MySQL error log when you looked at it. 'cause you looked there first, right?

Comment: Right, I tried telnet localhost 3306 and got this error: Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connection failed.

Answer (score 1):

Open up command prompt and type :

```
netstat -anto | findstr 3306
```

If you get output the mysql server is running , else the server is not running in this case check mysql service status in services.msc

Comment: That's not answering my question, but I get no output, just a blank line. I'm not having trouble running the sever - rather I'm having trouble connecting to it.

Comment: Got it! I used the steps outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547855/1130-host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server